# How to use this keyword in a static method in java?

Tags: java, android, static, this

Is there any way to use `this` keyword inside a static method in Java? I want to display a Toast message inside a static method in my activity class. How do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: What your situation to use this keyword in static method?

Comment: Edited my question. I have to display a Toast message in a static menthod

Comment: Add the incorrect code you would like to see work and let's see if someone knows a way around what you want to do.

Comment: @santhosh then what is the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a static method with one input parameter that is the Class you need to use.

For example:

```
public static void showMyTouch(MyActivity act, String message){
   Toast.makeText(act, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: +1 Replace `MyActivity` with `Activity` or `Context` to be more useful and general.

Comment: yes.we can use everything, this is a simple example for "Toast message" :D.Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 6):

Now what?

```
static void thisInStatic(){
    new Object(){
        Object instance = this;
    };
}
```

Comment: Well, `this` refers to the object you have created, but yeah +1, you did put `this` inside a static method ;)

Answer (score 3):

No. There is nothing for it to refer to.

Answer (score 0):

this refers to instance members and static method will only access static variable

Comment: Answer is basically meaningless.

Comment: @ejp i wish yo say what you have said i also have edited my answer

Comment: Now your *comment* is meaningless. You wish I had said what I said?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that "this" represents the object that invokes the method. Static methods are not specifically bound to any particular object. Rather, they are class level methods. That is why "this" cannot be used in static methods.

Answer (score -1):

This refers to the object that will be created. You can't access such object from staitc method. Put you attention on it. Here some useful link to you http://mindview.net/Books/TIJ4

Comment: Your first sentence is only true within a constructor. In other places where it is valid it refers to an object that already exists. -1